# main thread deadlock C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, deadlock, freeze

I'm debugging my application, but some module (probably custom) causes deadlock.
Main thread just freezes with some EIP and process hangs, thread info below
[thread list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLpLw.png)

How can I find out what causes this issue? Also, I tried to create dump file and analyze it using windbg and I got that stack:

```
0077d8ac 7693c9b8 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
0077d8c8 571a2ffd KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjects+0x18
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

The steps to follow is to first find out if you have any static variables. If yes, then you need to make it thread safe.

Also, if your code is the originator of the multiple threads, check if any data structure is shared with the new thread by any means. Then they also have to be made thread safe.

There may also be some implicit data structures shared... maybe some session... accessing these structures must be streamlined by wrapping these structures in a class and making it threadsafe - and mandating use of the new class over the data structure directly.

Answer (score 0):

What I would try is find the combination of these custom modules that cause the deadlock. Say if you have module A,B,C,D and only enable module A,D and you get the deadlock, then you should take further look into the modules.

Also add debug / log to your custom module in possible time consuming/infinite loop functions.